# AngularJS - Edit column value with applied filter

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am new to angular and ng-grid. I am using ng-grid as grid control in my project. I am trying to edit a cell whose value is formatted with a angular filter. For example:

```
{field:'rate | currency: "GBP "', displayName:'Rate'}
```

Here currency filter is applied to Rate column. When I click on the "Rate" column to edit, I get a blank textbox as in editable cell template. I was expecting to see the textbox bound to underlying data, but its not happening. Any idea?

Also, on blur or lost focus on cell, it should get out from editable template, even that is not happening. Anything I am missing?

Here is the plukr to see the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/W5aViYikZzEGnDPgSI5z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the cellFilter option. [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnmN4NSWiOpx5GA2lXs3?p=preview)

```
  columnDefs: [
    {
      field: 'name', 
      displayName: 'Name', 
      cellTemplate: 'input-tpls.html'}, 
    {
      field:'rate ', 
      displayName:'Rate',
      cellFilter: 'currency'
    }
  ],


  app.filter('currency', function () {
       return function (input) {
         //Do your formatting here.
         return "GBP " + input;
       };
   });
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! didn't know about cellFilter, but now addition to my knowledge.. :)